# Makefile: no rule to make target with variables

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to write a Makefile that when I add some deps in my application I just have to change DEPS_NAME variable, but something is wrong and I can't figure out what. I know that this is not the only problem with this Makefile, I just started to study this technology.

This is my project structure

```
application/
├── deps/
│   ├── buffer/
│   │   ├── buffer.c
│   │   └── buffer.h
│   └── other/
│       ├── other.c
│       └── other.h
├── objs/
├── application.c
└── Makefile
```

This is my Makefile

```
CC = gcc
APP_NAME = application

OBJS_PATH = objs
DEPS_PATH = deps
DEPS_NAME = buffer other

DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJS_PATH)/%.o,$(DEPS_NAME))

$(OBJS_PATH)/%.o: $(DEPS_PATH)/%/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^

$(APP_NAME): $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $@.c $^

all: $(APP_NAME)
```

This is the error when i type make:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `objs/buffer.o', needed by `application'.  Stop.
```

Comment: If 'buffer.c' needs any of the info in other.h -- or-- other.c needs any of the information in buffer.h,  then this makefile will also fail during the linking step.   It is possible to use the current file/directory architecture in a makefile, but would be much easier to write the makefile if all header files were in on directory and all source files in the same directory.

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for your suggestion, but the problem does not arise because deps are standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the object files in the same directory of the source files I solved the problem with this Makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Ideps
APP_NAME = application

DEPS_SOURCE = $(wildcard deps/*/*.c)
DEPS_OBJECT = $(DEPS_SOURCE:.c=.o)

all: $(APP_NAME)

$(APP_NAME): $(DEPS_OBJECT)
    $(CC) $@.c -o $@ $(DEPS_OBJECT) $(CFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^

clean:
    rm -f $(DEPS_OBJECT) $(APP_NAME)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Whit this solution I don't have to change the Makefile when I add other deps in the project.

Answer (score 0):

until you have determined the root cause of the problem, suggest a separate target for each *.c to *.o compile step.

you want the 'all' target to be the first target in the makefile. 
(that is what a 'all' target is for, so can call the makefile with:

```
make
```

without specifying a target in the make file

Note: 'all' is a phony target (produces no file named 'all')
so should be written similar to:

```
.PHONY: all
all : $(app_name) $(DEPS)
```

When make performs the compile step(s)
It needs to know how to find the header files.
and since the header files are scattered, 
it may be advisable to either 1) list all the paths/*.h files in the compile rule (simple but can result in unneeded compiles) or 2) generate dependancy files.(difficult, but best as the file count grows)  or 3) write a separate compile rule for each source file. (least flexable, but easy for those new to make)

the compile rule needs to have parameters indicating where to find the header files.   (in gcc, use '-I./other/.' and '-I./buffer/.)

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen multiple stem references. Looks like it badly confuses the parser.

On a bright side it seems that

```
$(OBJS_PATH)/%.o: $($(DEPS_PATH)/%/%.c)
```

does the trick. Don't ask me why.